# Split string in items

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a string

```
'a, b, c'
```

What is the easiest way to split this into items?

```
[a,b,c]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming you have a string (represented by an atom), you can write a procedure `atoms_list/2`:

```
atoms_list(Atom, List):-
  atomic_list_concat(['[', Atom, ']'], NAtom), 
  term_to_atom(List, NAtom).
```

Example:

```
?- atoms_list('a,b,c', List).
List = [a, b, c].
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the end

```
atomic_list_concat(L,', ', 'a, b, c').

L=['a','b','c']
```

Comment: beware that the use of atomic_list_concat/3 with the first argument uninstantiated is kept in SWI prolog for back portability; in fact the documentation states that the first argument should be instantiated.